# How would I use fread() for a partial read, and get my expected output here?

Tags: c, scanf, fread, partial, file-read

I am having difficulty with using the fread() function to read values from a file for a very specific and unlikely use case. This sounds really stupid, but an assignment I am working on requires me to do a partial read of items in a file.

My file name is "test_file.txt", and it's written in the following format, with one integer per line:

```
23
4
10
```

My code snippet, which is meant to process the above three bytes at a time, looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {

    int value = 0;
    char buffer[3];
    FILE* channel_file = fopen("test_file.txt", "rb");
    
    while(fread(&buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), channel_file) > 0) {

        sscanf(buffer, "%d", &value);
        printf("%d \n", value);
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    }
}
```

Since I am reading the file 3 bytes at a time, I was expecting it to look like this:

```
23\n
4\n1
0\n
```

which does seem to be the case (since \n counts as a byte). Printed, I wanted to see

```
23
41
0
```

However, when I try to print these values using the code above, I only get this:

```
23
4
```

I have tried a variety of different parameters in the fread() function itself, but none of them give the expected output. I was hoping someone more familiar with C and string parsing could help.

** EDIT: Posted a solution below. The solution is prone to undefined behavior since `buffer` and `str` are not null terminated. A mechanism for adding null termination to the `buffer` and `str` char array would improve the solution here.

Comment: `fread()` is not appropriate for reading variable-length text lines.  Use `scanf()` to read one integer at a time, or use either `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` to read a line at a time.

Comment: Is there any way of specifying the number of bytes to read with scanf or fgets()? I need to specify that to get the output I am looking for.

Comment: I understand that doing it this way is a horrible idea, and that line by line is way better. Unfortunately, the assignment I am doing requests I do it this way. If I do line by line, I will get 23, 4, 10 instead of 23, 41, 0.

Comment: One (moderately absurd) option is to read one byte at a time with `fread()` — `getchar()` or `getc()` would be more conventional for single-character I/O, of course.  One other (also moderately absurd) option would be to read 3 bytes at a time, but use `ungetc()` to unget the extra byte on the middle line — you spot that the newline appears at offset 1 instead of 2 and pushback the extra character you read 'by accident'.

Comment: Your final `fread()` only returns the remaining two bytes, so it doesn't satisfy your `while` condition, so nothing is printed. Solution: fix your code. It is hard to believe in the reality of this problem.

Comment: With `fgets()`, you must specify the maximum number of bytes — but you also need to allow for a terminating null byte (it reads a string, not a byte array).  With `scanf()`, you have some control over how many bytes are read for a number or for a string.  If you read numbers, you don't need to worry in this context.  If you read strings, `scanf()` will skip over white space (newlines, blanks, tabs, etc) and will stop at the next white space.

Comment: Your code has more than one problem. One, you actively reject partial reads. Two, you are using `sscanf` with a non-null-terminated buffer. Three, you appear to expect that the buffer `4\n1` will sscanf to 41.

Comment: Why are you expecting `41` as the second number? `%d` stops parsing the number at a non-numeric character, so `4\n1` will be parsed as `4`. You need to remove the newline from between the characters, and you have to add a null terminator.

Comment: I made a mistake in the initial code with the while loop condition, my apologies. It should be "> 0" rather than "== sizeof(buffer)". I've added a step where I check for and remove the "\n" character. I'll try to add a null terminator to the end of the buffer and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Given the sample data, it would be trivial to `fread()` up to 256 bytes into a buffer, terminate  the buffer, then use `strtol()` to convert each of the three numeric fields.

Comment: The precise wording of your assignment might be useful.  To verify your compression of the task.  It is not a given that the line ends are `\n`.  On Windows for example it is usual to have `,\r\n` line ends, and opening in binary mode will not translate them to a single `\n`. You should use text mode for portability.  It is not clear why you expected `41` not `4` when there is a newline between the digits.

Answer (score 3):

On review, the approach below, given OP's file input of `"23\n4\n10\n"`, prints:

```
23
4
10
```

This is **not** OP's goal of:

```
23
41
0
```

Seems I mis-understood OP's goal.
Making answer [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) for reference.

---

It appears OP is obliged to use `fread()` for input.  Sigh.

- Consider using `fread()` to read in *up to* so many characters.  Maybe up to 3 in this case.
- Open the file in *text* mode to handle systems that use `"\r\n"` as a single `'\n'`.  `fopen("test_file.txt", "rb")` --> `fopen("test_file.txt", "r")`.
- Make the buffer one larger so we can append a *null character* and process `buffer` as a *string*.  `sscanf(buffer...` expects a *string*.
- No need for `&buffer`. `buffer` itself will convert to the type of `&buffer[0]`.
- Use `" %n"` to store how many characters were consumed converting the string into an `int`.  Use that to adjust how many characters to read in the next `fread()`.
- No need for a space before printing a `'\n'`.
- Good practice: check return value from `sscanf()`.

```
   // Untested illustrative code.

    #define BUFFER_MAX_LEN 3
    char buffer[BUFFER_MAX_LEN + 1];
    size_t buffer_len = 0;  // Count of unprocessed characters in the buffer.
    size_t buffer_read;

    do {
      buffer_read = fread(&buffer[buffer_len], sizeof buffer[0], 
          BUFFER_MAX_LEN - buffer_len, channel_file);
      buffer_len += buffer_read;
      buffer[buffer_len] = '\0';  // Make buffer[] a string
      int n;
      int conversion_count = sscanf(buffer, "%d %n", &value, &n);
      if (conversion_count != 1) {
        printf("Nothing to convert from <%s>. Quitting\n", buffer);
        break;
      }
      printf("%d\n", value);
      buffer_len -= n;
      // Move unused trailing characters to the front.
      memmove(buffer, buffer + n, buffer_len);
    } while (buffer_read > 0);
```

---

- A more advanced approach would use a much larger buffer and look for multiple `int` in the string.  We could then reduce the wasteful `memmove()`.
- It is more robust to use `strtol()` than `sscanf(..."%d ...`

Leave those for a later day.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have made a very simple thing rather complicated. What you appear to require from your description is to:

> read the file three bytes at a time and to print *only* the digit characters from those three bytes on a new line.

A simple and clear statement of requirements leads to a simpler solution.  I wonder what the actual stated requirements were in the original assignment?

Given the *stated* precondition that the file contains only digits and newlines, then there is no need even to convert anything to an integer.  Neither is there any need for complex string manipulation or string termination.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    FILE* channel_file = fopen( "test_file.txt", "r");
    
    if( channel_file != NULL )
    {
        size_t count = 0 ;
        char buffer[3] ;

        while( 0 < (count = fread(&buffer, 1u, sizeof(buffer), channel_file)) ) 
        {
            for( size_t c = 0; c < count; c++ )
            {
                if( buffer[c] != '\n' )
                {
                    putchar( buffer[c] ) ;
                }
            }
            putchar( '\n' ) ;
        }
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Noting also that `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.  It is not wrong, but not necessary to ask the size of a `char`.

A "safer" method that does not rely on the file containing only digits and newline is to `#include <ctype.h>` then then change the digit output condition to:

```c
                if( isdigit( buffer[c] ) )
                {
                    putchar( buffer[c] ) ;
                }
```

If on the other hand the assignment *requires* you to determine an integer value, then the `while` loop body can be changed to:

```c
            unsigned value = 0 ;
            for( int c = 0; c < count; c++ )
            {
                if( isdigit( buffer[c] ) )
                {
                    value *= 10 ;
                    value +=  buffer[c] - '0' ;
                }
            }
            printf( "%u\n", value ) ;
```

avoiding any building of a string in order to perform the conversion.

Comment: Minor: suggest the same type for `count` and `c`.

Comment: "Given the stated precondition that the file contains only digits and newlines, then there is no need even to convert anything to an integer." --> Yes, but relying on assumptions causes brittle code.  Much like this good code does `if( channel_file != NULL )`, error checking is good and saves overall development time.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica : agreed, but there is a subtle difference between a precondition and an assumption.  A precondition is a statement of the conditions under which the code will work. In a real application it may be that the precondition is enforced elsewhere, and testing the validity of the input repeatedly through a call stack or data flow inefficient. In this case I used it to show how simple the code _could be_ given the specified input.  The alternative suggestions are however only marginally more complex and not reliant on the precondition.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica .... The assignment is already weird - there may unstated constraints on a solution such as library usage etc. so I provided three.  As I commented, the precise wording of the assignment would help.